# Node Worker thread is not working inside api call

Tags: node.js, express, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

I am using node version 16 and following all documented steps. Still worker thread is not working.

`

```
const addPaymentApi = async (req) => {
    const { payload, adminId } = req.body;
    logInfo(`Request to Create payment!`, {
        adminId
    });

    const createPaymentResponse = await composeResult(
        (response) => {
            const worker = new Worker("../workers/bulk-add-payment-api.worker.js");
            worker.on("message", (data) => {
                //update response table
            })
            return Result.Ok(response);
        },
        () => db.create(new CreateBulkUploadResponse(adminId))
    )({ payload, adminId });
    return respond(
        createPaymentResponse,
        `Payments processed Sucessfully!`,
        `Not Able to process payments!`,
    );
}
```

Code inside worker file is not getting executed

I tried every possible solution. I want to create a worker thread and perform CPU extensive task.

Comment: Is code inside `(response) => { }` executed?

Comment: Yes it is executing.